# Как вписать текст вводимый пользователем в переменную? В боте вк на vk_bottle

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Как сделать чтобы бот вк запрашивал у пользователя имя, и сохранял его в переменную. А при команде "моё имя" отправлял ту самую переменную?

Comment: главное чтобы имя бралось не из профиля пользователя, а имя устанавливаемое в самом боте

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и перенесите в него свой комментарий

Comment: мне нужно чтобы бот запрашивал у человека имя, и сохранял его, и при определённой команде он отправлял это же имя человеку. И так нужно для всех пользователей

Answer (score 1):

Для этого Вам нужно создать три [хендлера](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/high-level/handling/handler/): первый спрашивает как зовут пользователя и записывает на него [стейт](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/high-level/handling/state-dispenser/), второй после ответа на вопрос — записывает в базу данных пользователя, а третий обрабатывает команду "моё имя", то есть выводит информацию из базы.

---

1. Импортируем нужные библиотеки в дальнейшем

```
import asyncio
import aiosqlite
from vkbottle import BaseStateGroup
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
```

2. Указываем токен бота вашей группы

```
bot = Bot(token="ваш токен")
```

3. Создаем [стейт](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/high-level/handling/state-dispenser/) для веточной системы обслуживания сообщений

```
class Registration(BaseStateGroup):
    NAME = 0
```

4. Нам нужно асинхронно добавлять информацию в базу данных, поэтому воспользуемся [aiosqlite](https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/en/stable/index.html).

add_user_into_database — принимает айди пользователя (user_id) и указанное имя (user_name), после записывает в таблицу.

take_name_user_from_database — принимает лишь айди пользователя (user_id), если обнаружит запись с данным айди, то возвращает записанное имя пользователя, иначе вернёт None.

```
async def add_user_into_database(user_id, user_name):
    connection = await aiosqlite.connect('путь к базе данных')
    command = await connection.execute("INSERT INTO наименование_таблицы VALUES(?, ?)", (user_id, user_name))

    await connection.commit()
    await command.close()
    await connection.close()


async def take_name_user_from_database(user_id):
    connection = await aiosqlite.connect('files/testing.db')
    command = await connection.execute("SELECT имя FROM наименование_таблицы WHERE айди_пользователя = ?", (user_id, ))
    result = await command.fetchone()

    await command.close()
    await connection.close()

    return result[0]
```

5. Создаем ранее описанные выше [обработчики](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/high-level/handling/handler/).

```
@bot.on.message(text="Указать имя")
async def start_handler(message: Message):
    await bot.state_dispenser.set(message.from_id, Registration.NAME)
    await message.answer("Как вас зовут?")


@bot.on.message(state=Registration.NAME)
async def registration_name_handler(message: Message):
    await bot.state_dispenser.delete(message.from_id)
    await asyncio.create_task(add_user_into_database(user_id=message.from_id, user_name=message.text))


@bot.on.message(text="Моё имя")
async def send_name_handler(message: Message):
    name = await asyncio.create_task(take_name_user_from_database(user_id=message.from_id))
    if name:
        await message.answer("Вас зовут: " + name)
    else:
        await message.answer("Ваше имя не записано.")
```

6. Запускаем пуллинг.

```
bot.run_forever()
```

---

Вместо [aiosqlite](https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/) можете воспользоваться [CtxStorage](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/tools/storage/), однако, он будет обнуляться с каждым запуском программы.